# Java App testing error

Tags: java, android, class, classnotfound

I am using Eclipse IDE and Java and trying to instantiate `androidvnc` and I receive this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{android.androidVNC/android.androidVNC.androidVNC}: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.androidVNC.androidVNC
```

What does the error mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Check your Manifest file, do you have the other activity you're trying to open described there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception means that the android launcher cannot find the following activity class:

```
android.androidVNC.androidVNC
```

The main class is declared in your `manifest.xml` file.

Check that your `manifest.xml` declares the class correctly. Also check that you actually have the androidVNC class in the right package (android.androidVNC) and you didn't somehow move it into your own package.

In Eclipse the file should be located in src/android/androidVNC/androidVNC.java

Comment: I see, I'll dig in to. I tried to refactor and rename it to see if the manifest will update and it did. will check the other options and also dig deeper on this topic. many thanks for your help :D

Comment: No worries. This is a really common error, we've all done it. Good luck :-)